# Control Entry to static library (.a) and never returns

Tags: c, linux

I have linked the static library with my code (.a) . But during run time , the control passes to library on the call to API, but it never returns,

```
ex: archived test_func.o in test.a which has implementation test_func(),
    calling test_func() from main.c

    Printf("inside main now")
    test_func();
    Printf("returned from lib - in main");

    the second printf, never gets called and the message never gets displayed on the console.
```

Can some one suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show the code for test_func function?

Comment: its getting compiled properly and there were no dangling pointers ,

Comment: @Naren Maybe the test_func() has an infinite loop ? How could we know ? Maybe it tries to read from stdin, and blocks ? Maybe it opens a socket, and listens for an incoming connection ? Or maybe you're just not flushing the output of your 2. printf ? Please help us help you. Show the details..

Answer (score 0):

If it never prints the second message then either it's exiting in the function (in which case your program should complete) or `test_func()` has an infinite loop (though keep in mind that it could just be taking longer than you're prepared to wait).

Without seeing the code to `test_func()`, we can't say for sure where the problem lies specifically.

If you don't have the source code to `test_func()`, then the best you'll be able to do is run it and then cause a core dump from outside, such as with `kill -6`. Then you could load the executable and core file into `gdb` to try and figure out what it was doing.

I should stress this won't be easy if the objects within the library don't include debugging information but you have to play the cards you're dealt.